# Client-Side API for Discord (Python)

Tags: python, discord

Is there a Python Client-Side API for Discord?
I don't need much, just to listen to events like getting a call or a message.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Note that selfbots are against TOS, and you could be banned without warning.


Sounds like you want a selfbot.

What you might be looking for is [Discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), many selfbots are written in that, such as:
https://github.com/appu1232/Discord-Selfbot

If you would rather not get banned, discord.py is still good for scripting bots for servers.

Comment: Thanks, but why are self bots against the TOS?

Comment: @It'sPotatoTime Flooding dms, spamming.

Comment: "discord.py is still good for scripting server side bots." bots as well as normal users are clients. They connect to the discord server.

Comment: How could I use discord.py to detect messages and calls on my account?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use discord.py to detect events on your account

Answer (score 0):

Ok late answer but maybe someone can benefit from it so here goes.
Never use discord.py for selfbots. Discord.py was created to work on bot accounts not user accounts. That being said, a lot of things in discord.py will flag your account.

If you want, you can use what I'm currently developing with Merubokkusu: [discum: discord selfbot api wrapper](https://github.com/Merubokkusu/Discord-S.C.U.M)

Here's the classic ping-pong example:

```py
import discum
bot=discum.Client(token=yourtoken)

@bot.gateway.command
def pingpong(resp):
    if resp.event.message:
        m = resp.parsed.auto()
        if m['content'] == 'ping':
            bot.sendMessage(m['channel_id'], 'pong')

bot.gateway.run()
```

Here's a ping-pong example where you don't reply to yourself:

```
import discum
bot=discum.Client(token=yourtoken)

@bot.gateway.command
def pingpong(resp):
    if resp.event.message:
        m = resp.parsed.auto()
        if m['author']['id'] != bot.gateway.session.user['id']
            if m['content'] == 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage(m['channel_id'], 'pong')

bot.gateway.run()
```

here's another example, this one appends live messages to a list:

```
import discum
bot=discum.Client(token=yourtoken)

messagelist = []

@bot.gateway.command
def pingpong(resp):
    if resp.event.message:
        messagelist.append(resp.raw)

bot.gateway.run()
```

Also, if you're just doing this in the terminal and don't want to reinitialize your gateway every time, you can just clear the commands you've set
`bot.gateway.clearCommands()`
and clear the current (gateway) session variables
`bot.gateway.resetSession()`

Discum is intended to be a raw wrapper in order to give the developer maximum freedom. It's also written to be relatively-simple, easy to build-on, and easy-to-use. Hope this helps someone! Happy coding!